# How to attach VSCode Debugger to a Hardhat Task's callback in setAction() so that breakpoints work?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'd like my code execution to pause on some expressions inside of the actions callback inside setActions. When i run the below config and breakpoint the debugger runs and exits immediately without stopping at the breakpoint.

```
// Filename : DoSomething.js

task("DoSomething", "DoesSomething")
  .addParam("account", "The account's address")
  .setAction(async () => {

   // breakpoint somewhere here!


});
```

My launch.json configuration looks like this:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Do Something",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tasks/admin/DoSomething.js",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/hardhat",
            "runtimeArgs":["--network", "goerli", "--account", "0xMyAddress1234555....."]
        }
    ]
```

Im guessing that the action gets registered in hardhat's internals and is passed as a copy so maybe that line is not directly executed?  Really keen to understand what's going on here!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use this Auto Attach toggle in VSCode's debugger[1] to achieve helpful progress on debugging hardhat tasks.

[1] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach